# libspotify API: Any simple way to get artist URI by a given artist name?

Tags: spotify

To get artist URI by a given artist name, the only way I could think of is to

1. *search artist:$artistname*;
2. compare the input $artistname with the artist name from the search results.
3. if 2. matches, get the artist URI.

Is there any simpler way to get the artist URI?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word: No. The API doesn't work that way I'm afraid.